# Should I separate it to different view or keep them in the same file with conditional rendering?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following database tables in my Laravel app:

- maintenance
- room
- equipment
- equipment_maintenance
- room_maintenance

`maintenance` has the following fields:

- ID
- name
- type

`equipment` has the following fields:

- ID
- name

`room` has the following fields:

- ID
- name
- equipmentId

The relationship between the tables `maintenance` and `equipment` and `room` is many to many.

I have a Laravel Controller called `MaintenanceController` that has `index`, `show`, `create`, `store`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy`.

Since the `maintenance` model has two types, `equipment_maintenance` and `room_maintenance`, should I do some logic within the `MaintenanceController` `show` method to handle conditional rendering or should I separate into another dedicated controller and also different view blade?

- Update
  Sorry for the confusion. I will try to explain better. In my `MaintenanceController`'s `show` method I have the following code.

```
Public function show($maintenceId)
{
  $maintenace = Maintenance::findOrFail($maintenaceId);
  $maintenace->with('equipments', 'rooms');

  return view('maintenance.show', compact($maintenace);
}
```

In my maintenance.show.blade.php, I have this block of code with the logic I am referring to

```
@includeWhen($maintence->type === 'equipment_maintenance', 'equipment-table);
@includeWhen($maintence->type === 'room_maintenance', 'room-table');
```

Since I have two types of maintenance, should I move it to their own dedicated view blade like `equipment-maintenace-show.blade` and `room-maintenace-show.blade` or keep them all in the same files using the `includeWhen`?

I have tried separating them into their own controller per type. `EquipmentMaintenanceController` and `RoomMaintenanceController` and their own separate Laravel blade view. I am not sure if it is the right choice. Looking for more ideas how to make the code better and reusability.

Comment: why does the room have a single `equipment_id`? Can both equipment and rooms be under maintenance unrelated to each other?

Comment: The room has equipment_id because equipments and rooms have a one to many relationship. I am not sure what you mean by the second question. @krisgjika

Comment: Do you relate rooms and maintenances via a pivot table and equipments and maintenances via another pivot table, or do you relate all three via one pivot table?

Comment: I relate them into separate pivot table. Room and Maintenance will have its own pivot table and Equipment and Maintenance have its own.

Comment: I dont understand the question. How are we supposed to know if "should I do some logic within the MaintenanceController show method to handle conditional rendering or should I separate into another dedicated controller and also different view blade?" Like what is happening there, where is what logic?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have made an update on what logic I was referring to.

Comment: Is it possible for a maintenance model to have a room AND equipment relationship simultaneously? If so, it would make sense to use the maintenance controller to show a list of rooms and equipment. I don't think there is anything wrong with your conditional includes approach. If you were showing information about a specific room or equipment, then I would use a RoomMaintenanceController or EquipmentMaintenanceController.

Also, separate pivot tables sounds like overkill. I think a morph to relationship makes more sense.

Comment: @msmahon Maintenance model could not have a room and equipment relationship simultaneously. The maintenance must display the only one of the corresponding relationship. So if one of the maintenance row is type `Equipment Maintenance`, then it must return `$maintenance->with('equipments')`. Maybe the approach of a single action RoomMaintenanceController or EquipmentMaintenanceController could be the right choice.